# How would I go about taking a screenshot of the screen except for a specific window/application

Tags: windows, screenshot, fullscreen

In this case I want to take a full screen screenshot, except for a specific application. This application is an Application which is Always On Top, Click Through, and full screen, however I need to screenshot everything behind it, without minimizing it. 
Is this possible?

Comment: This might help: http://www.wikihow.com/Take-a-Screenshot-in-Microsoft-Windows

Comment: Related: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/28333/selecting-two-windows-at-the-same-time-on-windows-7